# Is it possible to use google recaptcha on client side without server side support? If possible how?

Tags: client-side, nuxtjs2

Currently, I am working on Nuxtjs 2 project in which I have to implement Recaptcha on the client side, I do not want backend support for Recaptcha. I want to handle it only on the front end. How can I do this on the front-end with or without any library that is compatible with nuxtjs2?

Answer (score 0):

There is **no reason** to use reCAPTCHA without server.
reCAPTCHA is for protecting the backend from spam.

If you really want to do it, you can make the same request with JavaScript.

But again: **Makes no sense.**

reCAPTCHA validation for PHP:

```
function validate_captcha_response($code){
  if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="localhost") return true;
  if($code && strlen($code)>32){
    $secret = "<your reCaptcha v3 secret>";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $gcaptcha = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$code&remoteip=$ip"), true);
    return ($gcaptcha['success'] == true && $gcaptcha['score'] >= 0.8 && $gcaptcha['hostname'] == $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
  }
  return false;
}
```

The same code in JavaScript:

```
function validate_captcha_response(code){
  if(window.location.hostname=="localhost") return true;
  if(code && code.length>32){
    let secret = "<your reCaptcha v3 secret>";
    let gcaptcha = json_decode(file_get_contents(`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secret}&response=${code}`), true);
    return (gcaptcha['success'] == true && gcaptcha['score'] >= 0.8 && gcaptcha['hostname'] == window.location.hostname);
  }
  return false;
}
```

(Please note I removed the IP functionality)

Code Source: https://www.custom-captcha.com/